# Let $x \in B.$ And suppose $x \not\in A.$ And let $y \in A$. Then $x \neq y.$ Thus, $\forall x \in B$ and $\forall y \in A,$ $x \neq y$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Why is this not true? I wrote this for a proof, but I do not buy it. Something is wrong. Can you explain to me what it is?

Let $x \in B.$ Suppose $x \not\in A.$ Let $y \in A$. Then $x \neq y.$  And since $x, y$ were chosen arbitrarily we know that $\forall x \in B$ and $\forall y \in A,$ $ x \neq y$.

Answer (score 2):

From initial you take from $B$ not arbitrary $x$, but with condition $x \notin A$, which is $x \in B \setminus A$, so in end you cannot use $\forall x \in B$.